# What are the units of Y-axis in this perfmon graph in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, performance-testing, server

I have been monitoring server side performance. I got some graph based on the reading, but I am not able to figure out the unit on the y-axis numbers. Is the CPU utilization calculated in % or some other unit? And what about memory, Network I/O, Swap memory??? Can any one suggest something.[image: Is the unit on y-axis is bytes???]

Answer (score 3):

For particular your image Y axis stands for [Swap (page) file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging) usage in bytes depending on chosen [metric](https://github.com/undera/perfmon-agent/blob/master/README.md#swap-metrics) which could be one of:

- used
- pagein
- pageout
- free
- total

You can calculate percentage for swap file as `used/total * 100`. For other metrics you will need to play the same trick.

See [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) article for more information on monitoring server-side performance counters with PerfMon